# Ruby on Rails: Nested Attributes, saving multiple records in single text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I save multiple records with nested attributes using single text_area? Each line in the text box or separated by a comma should be a separate record.

How would the controller look?

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |g| %>
    <%= render 'product_fields', :f => g %>
  <% end%>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :products %>

<% end %>
```

**_product_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :category, placeholder: "Category" %>
<%= f.text_area :item, placeholder: "List your products (separated by each line or comma)" %>
```

**project_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js

    if @project.save

      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id,  
    products_attributes: [:id, :item, :hyperlink, :_destroy, :category]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

I would like to go into my project form, and then there's a large text_area where I can add a list of products, and each product (separated by "enter" or a "comma") will be a record.

EDIT ----

Adding Models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Comment: If you're going to use a single text_area that will be automatically associated to project.products, then you would not need `simple_fields_for` and `link_to_add_association`, because but it is repetitive (unless this is intentional). What I meant by that is that your user can type into one text area, let's say (banana, orange). But then he also clicks `add item` thereby bringing up a new text area in which he could enter 'apple'. Then at the end, he would see two text areas (one text area: he typed `banana, orange` and another text area `apple`

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I don't want to do it this way because thats extra work (clicking a button). If you're able to just press enter, wouldn't that be faster? Or.... the time of this writing, I'm thinking maybe I can use jQuery, and if user is in the text box, and when presses "enter", it'll be for 'add item'... but how would I do that? 

The `add item` button I have now is for categorizing the list. So each text_box (when added) is going to be a different category in the `project` object, and each separated line is a product.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you save your params without much manipulation. If you want to turn your text_area param into multiple records just chop it up and process it in the controller.

Let's say you use a new line to delineate products so your text area looks like:

product1
product2
product3

```
project_params[:product_list] = "product1\nproduct2\nproduct3"
prod_arr = project_params[:product_list].split("\n")
prod_arr.each do |product|
  #you now have your product name in the local variable product
  #you can now save each one separately. You will probably
  #need to take common items of the params hash and insert the 
  #current product, then save.
end
```

You can choose to split on just about any character. But pick one that makes sense and then also apply some sort of checking on the string you are splitting. Notice the `split("\n")` is using double quotes, that is needed to tell Ruby that you are talking about the newline character. If you used `split('\n')` it won't work.

I would also look at wrapping it in a transaction if you want to make sure they all save.

Comment: Also if you intend to be able to go back and edit/update in a similar manner you will have to pass the products as some sort of collection with their `:id` so you can update them, not create all new records.

Comment: How would this look with my controller? Would this be under `if @project.save`?

Comment: You've got a pretty complex form/controller going on here. Can you post all of your relevant model code? It would be easier for me to see how `project -> category -> product` all relate.

Comment: The code I provided would wrap the `.save` method. But without a lot more complex code in your form and elsewhere, you aren't going to be able to just use `@project.save` to do the work. Just the fact that you are asking how to `save multiple records` should tip you off that unless you can provide the data in the params hash exactly how the nested_attributes expect it to be laid out, you can't just do it with one call. I would recommend figuring out how to do this in the console, then translate that to your form/controller. But post more code as recommended and I'll keep trying to help.

Comment: I've updated my original post. Category is just an extra field, where I'm just trying to save this for each record with the products. Is this too complex?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you should go to another question and look at someone else's code. Does it immediately make sense to you? Maybe one of the SO members with 20K points can do this in their head, but most people can't get your intent without seeing all of your code. Always post way more code than you think you need to.

Comment: Also you have not posted the models. And remember we can't see your database so we have NO idea what columns you have in it. If you have code posted on a site like github, you should include a link to that.

Comment: Hi! my model is really simple, just accepts nested attributes to products, and products belongs to project. Maybe i'll have to start a bounty

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good enough yet to write you code that I can't test locally, wish I was. My answer above is pretty much how the logic works. Have you tried to adapt it at all? You can either have a dynamic form, i.e. every time you add a product to a single line text field some javascript creates a new blank field below it for the next one, or you can accept a string, chop it up in the controller and feed each record to the DB in a `.each` loop like I've outlined.

Comment: https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields  This is a gem that lets you generate a product field in a nested form. But as you said up top, you don't want to have to click a button. One thing you could do is use AJAX to watch the blank field, when it gets filled and the user hits <enter> it can fire the action to create another field. `accepts_nested_attributes` should ignore the blank field that will always be there at the end if done this way.